# UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage sometimes doesn't take immediate effect

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm resetting the NavigationBar's background image by calling `setBackgroundImage` when showing an `MFMailComposeViewController`.  But when I try to reset the image to its original by calling `setBackgroundImage` a second time in `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:`, it doesn't visibly change the background image.

The weird thing is that the log shows me that the NavigationBar's background image *has* changed, and after I pop a few view controllers (I'm not sure which are modal transitions and which aren't, because it's somebody else's code), the background image finally *does* change.  But why doesn't it change immediately?

Here's my relevant code inside `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:`:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
NSLog(@"Navbar img = %@", [[UINavigationBar appearance]
                            backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggestion is to make sure that you are setting the background image *after* you've dismissed the mailComposeController and *after* your own view controller has become active again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your -mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult: is being called on the main thread, where you need to be doing all of your ui work?

Try executing your -setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: call on the main thread and see if this helps.

For example:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]
                                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alex, for the help- I'm not sure that it is being called on the main thread, but adding the `dispatch_async` block inside `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult` didn't change the behavior.

Comment: @Josh

It was worth a shot :)

The other place I'd look is to make sure that you are setting the background image -after- you've dismissed the mailComposeController and -after- your own view controller has become active again.

Comment: That worked for me!  The trick was to call `setBackgroundImage` inside `viewWillAppear` in the view controller that called the mailComposeController.  Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?